# Vuetify: Wrong behavior in the v-navigation-drawer component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Until version 2.6.1, the component worked correctly when used with the "mini" variant. However, since Vuetify version 2.6.2, it always collapse after interacting with the navigation, having the "permanent" property set.

```
<v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant.sync="mini"
      permanent
    >
       ***
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

I have created a codepen with the behavior of version 2.6.2:

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/fimhoff/pen/NWaOWOa)

This is a bug or did something change in the behavior of the component?

Comment: Looks like it's a bug that already listed in [issue 14555](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/14555) and fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/commit/bb2b11e3d0f39fe286b83792072afd4e97ce8121). I guess the commit will go into one of the next versions.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!